# continuity of functional in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I came across this problem and got confused

**Problem:** Define $h:C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ by $$h(x)=\sup_{0\leq t\leq1}|x(t)|$$Show $h$ is continuous in $C[0,1]$

**Attempt:** I am a bit confused with this problem because it didn't mention the which metric we are using..Is specifying a norm for space $C[0,1]$ necessary in this case? Is the supremum functional a linear functional? I am new to this stuff.. The idea to this whole functional thing is a bit confusing to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, $C[0,1]$ is equipped with the sup-norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ wrt $[0,1]$. Note that in this case, $h(x)=||x||_\infty$, so $h$ maps each element of the vector space $C[0,1]$ to its norm!

What we have to do here is to show that $h$ is continuous, that is, if $x$ is any continuous function on $[0,1]$, and $x_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly (that is wrt the sup-norm) to $x$, then $h(x_n)$ has to converge to $h(x)$. Ok, lets do this.
$$
|h(x_n)-h(x)|=\left|||x_n||_\infty-||x||_\infty\right|\leq||x_n-x||_\infty\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$, because $x_n$ converges uniformly to $x$. Thus we have shown that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(x_n)=h(x)$, and since $(x_n)$ was arbitrary this shows that $h$ is indeed continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The metric is the $\sup$. You can show this is a metric in the usual way.

Comment: what if I let $h(x)=\sup x(t)$ by taking out the absolute value? Is this still continuous?

Comment: It would be funny if the problem is asking to prove that the sup norm is continuous in the sup norm. For that matter, one can show that any metric is continuous in itself, by taking $\delta=\varepsilon $.

Answer (score 0):

$h$ maps continuous functions $x$ to real numbers. You want to show $h$ is continuous which means that for fixed $x$ and $\epsilon>0$, $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$. The question is what $\|x-y\|<\delta$ means. Presumably the problem means that $\|x-y\|$ is the sup norm.

Comment: Okay..I get it.. What if i change it to $sup$ without the absolute value? Will this still be continuous?